# Spring ACL with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, acl, ehcache-3, ehcache-2

I have an implementation using Spring Boot 2 and ACL component, I followed this guide for ACL implementation: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-acl

Now I am updating my application to Spring Boot 3 but there are some classes where maybe does not exist or is deprecated, for example `EhCacheFactoryBean`, `EhCacheManagerFactoryBean` and `EhCacheBasedAclCache`.

I am searching some updated guide of this implementation but i can't find it, please help :(

Thanks !

I tried to update all dependencies of Spring Boot to version 3, i fixed the 99% of my application but I can't fix the ACL classes.